# Excel Table - Filter Table with Multiple Sub-Headings

Tags: excel, vba, filter

[image: Example Table]
*Example table is entirely fictitious*

The example image shows a timetable rota for individuals at a company divided into departments. Entries span into the hundreds in the actual spreadsheet, and the desire is to quickly filter by various criteria for simple viewing and editing.

The timetable is inserted into Excel as a table (though it could be a simple range) and has 2 additional sub-headers for 'Procurement' and 'Analysis' however when filtering, these headers are hidden (as they are 'Blanks'), which is of particular importance when filtering by Group. How do I get this to work - A simple filter, allowing multiple (potentially pre-definable grouped) criteria while keeping the sub-headers visible.

**Limitations**

- The data in the rota is editable. It is not pulled, and edits to entries will be made directly to the cells within that table. This makes PivotTable and PowerQuery unusable to my understanding.
- Online Excel is often used, so ideally the solution should be compatible (so no Macros).

**Attempted**

- Multiple Tables: Having multiple tables excluding the sub-Headers means they won't be filtered, but Slicers cannot apply across multiple tables
- Slicers: Quick and efficient, however cannot have single click inputs to also include 'Blanks'
- Table Filters: Could work with the selection of 'Blanks' but is a far from optimum solution for simple usage.
- Button with VBA filtering: Potential solution, but would require all users to use the Desktop App.
- Other methods to get the header rows to Unhide once filters are applied, but cannot find a way to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried to use the automatic outline feature (change your table to a range, choose Data/Outline/Subtotal, at each change of Department, add a subtotal to some random column, choose summary above data)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Slicers: Quick and efficient, however cannot have single click inputs to also include 'Blanks'" - if the data includes blanks then (blank) will appear in the Slicer

Comment: In the ideal solution, a person shouldn't have to also click 'Blanks' to add back headers. Every time they filter they'd have to do a multi-select filter and remember to click 'Blanks' - Except the first column where it'll appear as the sub-heading names.